# General purpose library render control to bitmap

Tags: bitmap, shared-libraries, windows-phone

I'm looking for a general purpose Nuget package/library to render a user control as a bitmap.  I can make this work with a known user control, including waiting for any Image controls to have their source loaded, but this isn't so easy as a general-purpose solution (pass a Control, return the bitmap).  I hoped that the Measure/Arrange calls coupled with SizeChanged/Loaded/LayoutUpdated events would help me know when everything was completely ready, but the events don't load when I expect them to.  Is there any solution out there that I'm not aware of, or some way to wire up events better?

Answer (score 2):

You can render any control as a bitmap after the `Loaded` event has fired on your page. For example, below code should render your LayoutRoot and ContentPanel to bitmaps then save them as jpgs in your phone's picture library.

```cs
public MainPage() {
  InitializeComponent();

  Loaded += (s, e) => {
    SaveToMediaLibrary(GetBitmap(LayoutRoot), "LayoutRoot.jpg", 100);
    SaveToMediaLibrary(GetBitmap(ContentPanel), "ContentPanel.jpg", 100);
  };
}

private WriteableBitmap GetBitmap(FrameworkElement fe) {
  // This will make sure all content are sized properly before returning
  //fe.UpdateLayout();

  var bmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)fe.ActualWidth, (int)fe.ActualHeight);
  bmp.Render(fe, new MatrixTransform());         
  bmp.Invalidate();
  return bmp; 
}       

public void SaveToMediaLibrary(WriteableBitmap bitmap, string name, int quality) {   
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())            {         
    // Save the picture to the Windows Phone media library.             
    bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, quality);   
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);            
    new MediaLibrary().SavePicture(name, stream);        
  }     
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's true though.  Even though the page is loaded, Image controls will (may) load their source lazy, over a network connection, etc. and I don't think that you're guaranteed that it's available.  Are you *sure* that Loaded implies that *all* resources are ready?  It doesn't seem to fit what I see.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. In that case add `fe.UpdateLayout();` as the first statement in `GetBitmap()` method above. This will call element-specific `MeasureCore` and `ArrangeCore` methods which will also block current executing thread. In case of an image for example, the image will be downloaded when the method returns.